# Using sum in dplyr mutate with filter

Tags: r, dplyr

My dataframe looks like this:

```
"count","stock"
5,"Google"
21,"Google"
...
27,"Google"
30,"Google"
22,"Google"
4,"Google"
18,"Google"
4,"Google"
12,"Apple"
27,"Apple"
5,"Apple"
25,"Apple"
...
```

I want to add another column named `freq` with the relative frequency of each `count` value:

```
df_stock %>% mutate(freq = count/sum(df_stock[df_stock$stock == (.)$stock, ]$count))
```

My problem is that the selection for the current `stock` value is not working, meaning that `sum(df_stock[df_stock$stock == (.)$stock, ]$count)` returns the sum of all `count` values not just the ones for the corresponding stock under evaluation (e.g., `Google` or `Apple`).

Comment: You need to group by stock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
library(tidyverse)

df_stock %>%
  group_by(stock) %>% 
  mutate(freq = count/sum(count)
```

Comment: Thanks. Minor correction: `group_by(stock)` it is.

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
cbind(df, freq = with(df,  ave(count, stock, FUN = prop.table)))
```